# PNG image not displaying, using React

Tags: javascript

Hi does anyone know why my png file is not displaying, even if i set it outside of the button element, it does not work.

I have used a JPG and it works but PNG is not, is there any obvious reason why PNG would not be showing up.

Here is an image of my code
[Image of code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of8CJ.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask <= You need to improve your question, please read this

Answer (score 2):

First of all wrap the src in {}

Then if using Webpack; Instead of: `<img src={"./logo.jpeg"} />`

You may need to use require:

```
<img src={require('./logo.jpeg')} />
```

Another option would be to first import the image as such:

import logo from './logo.jpeg'; // with import

or ...

`const logo = require('./logo.jpeg);` // with require

then plug it in...

```
<img src={logo} />
```

I'd recommend this option especially if you're reusing the image source.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the full context, but assuming this React project is using webpack or was created with create-react-app, the image files in your `src` directory are not automatically being copied to the built application,
Try importing the image to the file where you use it:

```
import orbImage from "./org.png";
```

Then use it like so:

```
<img src={orgImage} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help you,

on the other hand for your next message try to review the formatting inspire you from the other posts thx

for your png maybe probleme is your src

```
// The image.png file must be in the same folder as the JS file
// We import the image using its path

import image from './image.png';
```

and maybe try to add width="200"